# Code First conventions for foreign keys and table names

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

Please accept my apologies for the large amount of text, I tried not to miss the details that may affect on something
Entity Framework 4.3.1
My Model:

```
public class Podcast
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int PodcastStatus_Id { get; set; }
    public int PodcastType_Id { get; set; }

    public virtual PodcastStatus PodcastStatus { get; set; }
    public virtual PodcastType PodcastType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CategoryLink> CategoryLinks { get; set; }
}

public class PodcastStatus
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Podcast> Podcasts { get; set; }
}

public class PodcastType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Podcast> Podcasts { get; set; }
}
```

Context:

```
public class EcDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<PodcastType> PodcastTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PodcastStatus> PodcastStatuses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Podcast> Podcasts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Podcast>().HasRequired(p => p.PodcastStatus).WithMany(s => s.Podcasts).HasForeignKey(p => p.PodcastStatus_Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Podcast>().HasRequired(p => p.PodcastType).WithMany(t => t.Podcasts).HasForeignKey(p => p.PodcastType_Id);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Query:

```
db.Podcasts.Where(p => p.PodcastStatus.SysStatus > 0 && p.Title.Contains(search))
    .OrderBy(p => p.CreatedDate)
    .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize)
```

Here I've deleted some columns from the Model descriptions so to not complicate things.
I get the following error message: `Invalid object name 'dbo.PodcastStatus'`. This table is named 'PodcastStatuses' in the database. We will see the following text if we look at the result SQL query:

```
    {SELECT TOP (10) 
[Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Project1].[Title] AS [Title], 
[Project1].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate], 
[Project1].[PodcastStatus_Id] AS [PodcastStatus_Id], 
[Project1].[PodcastType_Id] AS [PodcastType_Id], 
[Project1].[PodcastStatus_Id1] AS [PodcastStatus_Id1], 
[Project1].[PodcastType_Id1] AS [PodcastType_Id1]
FROM ( SELECT [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], [Project1].[CastNo] AS [CastNo], [Project1].[Title] AS [Title], [Project1].[OriginalText] AS [OriginalText], [Project1].[TranslateText] AS [TranslateText], [Project1].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate], [Project1].[PodcastStatus_Id] AS [PodcastStatus_Id], [Project1].[PodcastType_Id] AS [PodcastType_Id], [Project1].[ImageFileName] AS [ImageFileName], [Project1].[PodcastStatus_Id1] AS [PodcastStatus_Id1], [Project1].[PodcastType_Id1] AS [PodcastType_Id1], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Project1].[CreatedDate] ASC) AS [row_number]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[Title] AS [Title], 
        [Extent1].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate], 
        [Extent1].[PodcastStatus_Id] AS [PodcastStatus_Id], 
        [Extent1].[PodcastType_Id] AS [PodcastType_Id], 
        [Extent1].[PodcastStatus_Id1] AS [PodcastStatus_Id1], 
        [Extent1].[PodcastType_Id1] AS [PodcastType_Id1]
        FROM  [dbo].[Podcasts] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[PodcastStatus] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[PodcastStatus_Id] = [Extent2].[Id]
        WHERE ([Extent2].[SysStatus] > 0) AND ((N'' = @p__linq__0) OR ([Extent1].[Title] LIKE @p__linq__1 ESCAPE N'~'))
    )  AS [Project1]
)  AS [Project1]
WHERE [Project1].[row_number] > 0
ORDER BY [Project1].[CreatedDate] ASC}
```

`PodcastStatus_Id1, PodcastStatus_Id1, [dbo].[PodcastStatus] (and not 'statusES'), [PodcastStatus_Id] = [Extent2].[Id]`

Why? I don't understand what did I do wrong...
Can somebody help?
Thanks!

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? "Invalid object name 'dbo.PodcastStatus'" this? If so, try disabling the pluralization convention to check if that's the problem. If so, you can manually map an object to a table if you like to keep using pluralization.

Comment: Please update your title with a short description of your question. We try to keep things professional here.

Comment: @LeonCullens I had tried to disable the pluralization convention, but after I have got error with the PodcastStatus_Id1 column (which doesn't exist of course). The problem is that EF didn't understand that PodcastStatus_Id is foreign key. And I don't understand why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a problem when EF pluralizes names when generating the database - I ran across something like this a while ago but I forget which EF version.

You can force EF to name a table by using (although you will likely need to drop/recreate the database) :

```
[Table("PodcastStatus")]
public class PodcastStatus
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Podcast> Podcasts { get; set; }
}
```